# Text file parsing using helper class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a text file having list of movie names and its parts as below:

```
xxx, Author1, v6
the net, author1, v7
xxx, author3, v10
DDLJ, author3, v11
the fire, author5, v6
the health, author1, v8
the health, author7, v2
the hero, author9, v11
the hero, author8, v3
```

I would like to get most recent version of movie name. In this case it should return "DDLJ" and "the hero".

This is what I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ProgramNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static List<String> processData(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {           
            Dictionary<string, int> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                string[] readsplitted = item.Split(',');              
                keyValuePairs.Add(readsplitted[0], Convert.ToInt32(
                    Regex.Replace(readsplitted[2], "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)));
            }

            //List<String> retVal = new List<String>();
            return retVal;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                List<String> retVal = processData(File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\input.txt"));
                File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\output.txt", retVal);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, if required I would like to add a helper class.

Comment: Why do you have `processData` return an empty list always, after it does work? Did you mean to do that?

Comment: Just edited.I see, Dictionary is not taking duplicate values...Any other way?

Comment: To be clear, you don't want the name of the most version for *every* movie, you only want the names of the movie(s) for those with the highest version out of all of them.  Is that correct?

Comment: I edited my answer to take duplicated data into account

Comment: did you solve this @AskMe ?

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT: version for duplicated keys

I rewrote the first solution I gave to take duplicated data into account. The trick is adding a progressive number before the key and separating it with an underscore: this way every key will be unique.

E.g. you will have your Dictionary filled like this:

> "1_xxx", 6
>   "2_the net", 7
>   "3_xxx", 10
>   "4_DDLJ", 11
>   ...

Then I remove the number (and the underscore) before providing a result.

```
public static List<String> processData(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    var keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    int Position = 0;
    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
        Position++;
        string[] readsplitted = item.Split(',');
        keyValuePairs.Add(Position.ToString() +"_" + readsplitted[0], Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(readsplitted[2], "[^0-9]+", string.Empty)));
    }
    var MaxVersion = keyValuePairs.Values.OrderByDescending(f => f).First();

    return keyValuePairs.Where(f => f.Value == MaxVersion).Select(f => string.Join("_", f.Key.Split('_').Skip(1))).ToList();
}
```

More in detail:

- `keyValuePairs.Values` will return just the version numbers
- `.OrderByDescending(f => f).First()` will sort the version numbers in descending order and pick the first, i.e. the highest
- `keyValuePairs.Where(f => f.Value == MaxVersion)` will select the key-value pairs corresponding to the highest version above
- `.Select(f => f.Key)` will give you the keys of your `Dictionary`, i.e. the titles

This way you will also keep your `Dictionary`; *if you are doing this one time and you don't need to expand your code or reuse your models*, you won't have to create other classes or make it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: What's with the downvote? I tested the code and provided explanations and formatting...

Comment: Well I tried it. His code already removed the "v" and performed a conversion to `int`.

Comment: I get an `ArgumentException` was unhandled on the `Add` method with this method

Comment: It should be clear, since his dictionary is `Dictionary<string, int>` and I'm ordering on the `int` value. @RufusL

Comment: Please look at the data in the question. Dictionary can not take duplicate values. There will be exception.

Comment: @AskMe you edited the post. the data wasn't this when I wrote the solution.

Comment: @RufusL he edited the post and changed the data, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

For these kinds of tasks I usually prefer to create a class that represents the data we're collecting, and give it a `TryParse` method that will create an instance of the class based on a line of data:

```
public class MovieInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }

    public static bool TryParse(string input, out MovieInfo result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (input == null) return false;

        var parts = input.Split(',');
        int version;

        if (parts.Length == 3 &&
            int.TryParse(parts[2].Trim().TrimStart('v'), out version))
        {
            result = new MovieInfo
            {
                Name = parts[0],
                Author = parts[1],
                Version = version
            };
        }

        return result != null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} (v{Version}) - {Author}";
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of reading the file, creating a list of these classes, and getting all that have the highest number:

```
public static List<MovieInfo> processData(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    if (lines == null) return null;

    var results = new List<MovieInfo>();

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        MovieInfo temp;

        if (MovieInfo.TryParse(line, out temp))
        {
            results.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    var maxVersion = results.Max(result => result.Version);

    return results.Where(result => result.Version == maxVersion).ToList();
}
```

For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var lines = new List<string>
    {
        "xxx, Author1, v6",
        "the net, author1, v7",
        "xxx, author3, v10",
        "DDLJ, author3, v11",
        "the fire, author5, v6",
        "the health, author1, v8",
        "the health, author7, v2",
        "the hero, author9, v11",
        "the hero, author8, v3",
    };

    var processed = processData(lines);

    foreach (var movie in processed)
    {
        // Note: this uses the overridden ToString method. You could just do 'movie.Name'
        Console.WriteLine(movie);
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone!! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.  This accounts for getting all the movie names that where the max version is the same.

```
public static List<String> processData(string fileName)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

    var values = lines.Select(x => 
    {
        var readsplitted = x.Split(',');
        return new { Name = readsplitted[0], Verison = int.Parse(readsplitted[2].Replace("v", string.Empty))};  
    });

    var maxValue= values.Max(x => x.Verison);

    return values.Where(v => v.Verison == maxValue)
    .Select(v => v.Name)
    .ToList();  
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        List<String> retVal = processData(@"D:\output.txt");
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a `Movie` class in order to initialize objects for each row that represents a movie.
2. split the whole string passed to `processData()` first by new line that by ','.
3. extract the number of the version of each movie (sperate it from "v") see: `extractNumberFromString()` method.
4. find the max version number and get (using linq query) all the movies that share the maximum version number.

```
public static List<Movie> processData(string s)
{
    // list to store all movies
    List<Movie> allmovies = new List<Movie>();

    // first split by new line
    var splitbynewline = s.Split('\n');
    // split by ',' and initilize object
    foreach (var line in splitbynewline)
    {
        var moviestring = line.Split(',');
        // create new movie object
        Movie obj = new Movie { Name = moviestring[0], Author = moviestring[1], Version = moviestring[2] };
        obj.VersionNumber = extractNumberFromString(moviestring[2]);
        allmovies.Add(obj);
    }

    // get the max version number
    double maxver = allmovies.Max(x => x.VersionNumber);
    // set and returen list that containes all movies with max version
    List<Movie> result = allmovies.Where(x => x.VersionNumber == maxver).ToList();

    return result;
}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// convert number that exist in a string to an int32 for example sdfdf43gn will return as 43
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">string that contains inside him as digits</param>
/// <returns>int32</returns>
public static double extractNumberFromString(string value)
{
    string returnVal = string.Empty;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection collection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(value, "\\d+");
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in collection)
    {
        returnVal += m.ToString();
    }

    return Convert.ToDouble(returnVal);
}

public class Movie
{
    public string Name;
    public String Author;
    public string Version;
    public double VersionNumber;
}
```